# Get Merchant Information from QR code scan using PhonePe API in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, paytm, upi

I was wondering if there is any way to get the merchant information from a QR code like through flutter implementation so that I can use that information with phone pe/gpay/paytm APIs to make calls like different kind of requests.

Comment: Use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) to scan QR Code

Comment: If you decode some QR codes you should see if they contain any distinguishable "merchant information"?

Comment: @adadion Yes I am using that package to read the QR code .

Comment: Then you should get some kind of merchant id to lookup by API